# Reducing RGB color intensity in Ruby with Rmagick

Tags: ruby, image-processing, rmagick

I'm translating a function made with MATLAB that reduces the color intensity from an image's sector to Ruby using Rmagick

```
for i=round(f/3):f 
        for j=1:round(c)
            for k=1:p
            A(i,j,k) = B(i,j,k) - a;
            end
        end
    end

    for i=1:round(2*f/3)
```

This reduces the color intensity of all 3 RGB matrix by some value (a). Trying to reproduce this with ruby code yielded this:

```
(0..imagen.columns).each do |x|
  ((2 * imagen.rows) / 3..imagen.rows).each do |y|
    imagen.pixel_color(x, y, 'pink')
  end
end
```

I can change the lower third of my image to a set color, in this example, to pink.

Trying to reduce each component by some value (atenuacion) with each color's method won't work, it returns the same image.

```
(0..imagen.columns).each do |x|
  ((2 * imagen.rows) / 3..imagen.rows).each do |y|
    pixel = imagen.pixel_color(x, y)
    pixel.red - atenuacion
    pixel.green - atenuacion
    pixel.blue - atenuacion
    imagen.pixel_color(x, y, pixel)
  end
end
```

Any tips or suggestions are welcome, thank you in advance :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
pixel.red - atenuacion
pixel.green - atenuacion
pixel.blue - atenuacion
```

You're not changing the value of `pixel.red`, etc. You're just subtracting `atenuacion` from the value of `pixel.red` and then doing nothing with the result. Try this:

```
pixel.red -= atenuacion
pixel.green -= atenuacion
pixel.blue -= atenuacion
```

In the above, `pixel.red -= atenuacion` is shorthand for `pixel.red = pixel.red - atenuacion`. I'm just guessing that `pixel.red` et al are setters as well as getters. If not, you may need to do something like this instead:

```
pixel = imagen.pixel_color(x, y)

new_color = Magick::Pixel.new(
              pixel.red - atenuacion,
              pixel.green - atenuacion,
              pixel.blue - atenuacion,
              pixel.opacity)

imagen.pixel_color(x, y, new_color)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did what you told me and it's currently working, however, as you can see here: http://imgur.com/a/8osXN. It distorts the colors of the image instead of only reducing their intensity as you can see in my matlab example... Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know anything about MATLAB, nor much about image processing, but this bit from your code doesn't look the same as what you're doing in Ruby: `A(i,j,k) = B(i,j,k) - a;`. It seems to me that reducing the color intensity of a pixel is not the same as subtracting the same value from its red, green, and blue color values. For example, what if your values are *(125, 38, 205)*? If `atenuaction` is 128, the result is going to be *(-3, -90, 77)*. I don't know what RMagick does with negative values, but even if it just constrains them to zero that's probably not the result you were expecting.